# Error en Python al hacer Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Estoy tratando de hacer Scraping a una pagina web, pero me arroja el siguiente error.

```
C:\Users\dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/dani/PycharmProjects/Scraping/scrap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jdani/PycharmProjects/Scraping/scrap.py", line 6, in <module>
    page: object = request.get(url)
AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'get'
```

Este es el código que estoy probando, si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecería.

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import request
import pandas as pd

url = "https://resultados.as.com/resultados/futbol/primera/clasificacion/"
page: = request.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Equipos

eq = soup.find_all('span', class_='nombre-equipo')

equipos = list()

for i in eq:
    equipos.append(i.teext)

    print(equipos)
```

Saludos

DS

Comment: Hola Jose, ¿No será un typo? `import requests`; `page = requests.get(url)`
  Falta la "s" final, si como supongo quieres usar [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) Si no es así, ¿qué paquete es `request`?

Comment: Si es un typo, dado que el módulo existe, puede que también instalaras el paquete equivocado desde PyPi, verificarlo si te da un error de importación e instala `requests`.

Comment: Gracias, tenias la razon el problema era que faltaba la 's' al final del requests
Gracias
@FJSevilla